# how to print the heading from my appendix on the first page of an inserted pdf file

Tags: pdf, appendices, pdfpages

I have an appendix in my document but it only consists of a large pdf file. When I do it in the following way, I get my title from the Appendix at the end of the previous page or on a new page, but not on the first page of the real appendix.

```
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{mybib}

\cleardoublepage

\begin{appendices}
    \chapter{Appendix A}
    \label{ApA}
    \includepdf[pages={1}]{EPVDP.pdf}
    \includepdf[pages={2-}]{EPVDP.pdf}
\end{appendices}
```

The thing is: I want to crop the first page of the pdf, in order to fit the title and the chapter title right above the 'first page'. Is this possible?

Comment: Try to use `\appendix` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution, but it is only possible when your first page is not a full text page.
Saving the first page of the pdf as a figure and adding it in solves the problem.

```
\onecolumn 

\begin{appendices}
    \chapter{Appendix A}
    \label{ApA}
    \begin{figure}[ht!]
        \centering
        \centerline{\epsfig{figure=firstpage.jpg,width=\textwidth,height=22cm}}
    \end{figure}
    \includepdf[pages={2-}]{EPVDP.pdf}
\end{appendices}
```